# GBQ SQL: Find instance of X and pull corresponding row data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that records the history of each ID per LOCATION. This table is updated each day to keep track of the history of any change in a certain row(ID). Note: The date field is not in chronological order.

```
ID   Location   Count   Date (datetime type)
1    A          20      2020-01-15T12:00:00.000
1    A          10      2020-04-15T12:00:00.000
1    A          15      2020-03-15T12:00:00.000
1    B          10      2020-05-15T12:00:00.000
1    B          5       2020-06-15T12:00:00.000
1    B          0       2020-07-15T12:00:00.000
2    A          18      2020-01-15T12:00:00.000
2    A          0       2020-04-15T12:00:00.000
2    A          14      2020-03-15T12:00:00.000
2    B          10      2020-05-15T12:00:00.000
2    B          5       2020-06-15T12:00:00.000
2    B          1       2020-07-15T12:00:00.000
```

For each unique ID, I need to pull the first instance (oldest date) when the Count value is zero. If a unique ID does not have an instance where it Count value is zero, I need to pull the most current Count value.

Here's what my results should look like below:

```
ID   Location   Count   Date (datetime type)
1    A          10      2020-04-15T12:00:00.000
1    B          0       2020-07-15T12:00:00.000
2    A          0       2020-04-15T12:00:00.000
2    B          1       2020-07-15T12:00:00.000
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to code this in Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE
  CASE COUNTIF(count = 0) 
    WHEN 0 THEN ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
    ELSE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY count, date LIMIT 1)
  END [OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY id, location
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row id  location    count   date     
1   1   A   10      2020-04-15 12:00:00 UTC  
2   1   B   0       2020-07-15 12:00:00 UTC  
3   2   A   0       2020-04-15 12:00:00 UTC  
4   2   B   1       2020-07-15 12:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: You can use check sign to the left of the answer to accept it!